# skipping NULL output in apply

Tags: r, null, apply

When using apply in R, is there some way to have it skip over vector elements that are `NULL`, such that when `f(x2,y2)` is undefined `apply(x,1,f,y)` returns

`c(f(x1,y1),f(x1,y2),f(x2,y2))`
rather than
 `c(f(x1,y1),f(x1,y2),NULL,f(x2,y2))`?

Comment: I don't fully understand your example, but you should be able to do this: put your output in a variable, say `z`, and look at `z[!is.null(z)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afaik, not from inside the apply loop.

Your two options are:

1. to filter x & y. This can be done before calling apply, or in the actual apply call.  eg: `apply(x[index.x], 1, f, y[index.y])`
2. to filter the results after you get them.  eg

   `res <- apply(x,1,f,y)` 
      `res <- res[!is.na(res)]`

#### edit:

If going with the latter option, depending on what the output of your function is, either `is.null(res)` or `is.na(res)` will be the correct function to use.

Comment: I don't know before hand for which indices the function returns a null, so filtering x and y first isn't applicable here. I think that your second option will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `foreach` and outputting a `dataframe`:

```
foreach(i = 1:4, .combine = rbind) %do% {
  if (i == 3) {
    data.frame(i = numeric())
  } else {
    data.frame(i=i)
  }
}
```